# Diagnosing ENOMEM with popen() and system() calls in C++

Tags: c++, popen, errno, enomem

I'm dealing with a gargantuan C++ code for computational physics (that I didn't write) which calls other executables using `system()` calls. Sometimes in the middle of a simulation these `system()` calls will fail even for simple calls like `system("echo something);` When they fail they return immediately with return value -1.

I created a version of the code that uses `popen()` instead of `system()` to launch these other executables. In this version, popen() fails and errno is set to 12 (ENOMEM).

This is running on a machine with 96GB of RAM running CentOS 6.3 (via ROCKS 6.1) through the Torque PBS system.

Note that this behavior is somewhat uncommon, but it appears to happen for simulations which use large amounts of memory -- but far less than the amount of memory that is available.

I currently have a simulation running which is exhibiting this behavior. It is attempting to make a `system()` call every 30 seconds and failing, which allows me to monitor the OS memory resources. The contents of `/proc/meminfo` are

```
MemTotal:       99195180 kB
MemFree:         1758804 kB
Buffers:           14612 kB
Cached:         46502432 kB
SwapCached:         7004 kB
Active:         60758772 kB
Inactive:       35238760 kB
Active(anon):   45458924 kB
Inactive(anon):  4024068 kB
Active(file):   15299848 kB
Inactive(file): 31214692 kB
Unevictable:        9752 kB
Mlocked:            9752 kB
SwapTotal:       1023992 kB
SwapFree:         999432 kB
Dirty:                16 kB
Writeback:             8 kB
AnonPages:      49483620 kB
Mapped:            10292 kB
Shmem:                 8 kB
Slab:             235356 kB
SReclaimable:     193468 kB
SUnreclaim:        41888 kB
KernelStack:        2120 kB
PageTables:        99536 kB
NFS_Unstable:          4 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    50621580 kB
Committed_AS:   49576180 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      482936 kB
VmallocChunk:   34307833876 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     8 kB
AnonHugePages:  43315200 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        5568 kB
DirectMap2M:     2082816 kB
DirectMap1G:    98566144 kB
```

The contents of `/proc/5939/status` (which is the process in question) is

```
Name:   BAD_EXECUTABLE
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   5939
Pid:    5939
PPid:   5938
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    505     505     505     505
Gid:    505     505     505     505
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 256
Groups: 426 505 801 
VmPeak: 49733876 kB
VmSize: 49482532 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:  49721496 kB
VmRSS:  49470248 kB
VmData: 49481080 kB
VmStk:       128 kB
VmExe:      1316 kB
VmLib:         0 kB
VmPTE:     96656 kB
VmSwap:    10624 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   0/774828
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
Cpus_allowed:   ffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-23
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000003
Mems_allowed_list:      0-1
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        57003
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     1057385
```

I'm at a bit of a loss at how to debug this issue, especially since I can't recreate it with a smaller simulation. My simulation says it's using 47GB of memory, while `/proc/meminfo` shows that less than 2GB of 96GB of memory is free, and there shouldn't be anything else running that uses tens of GBs of memory.

[This forum](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/fopen-setting-errno-enomem-712304.html) seems to indicate that previous memory errors could have corrupted the heap. Is this a valid possibility? What else could I look at that would help me narrow down this issue?

Comment: That is odd! You should be getting ETOOMUCHMEMORY.

Comment: ENOMEM isn't necessarily that "there is no memory available", but "I couldn't find some memory to do what I wanted". This could, for example, be that the table in which the OS stores something is full, and that table is a fixed size.

Comment: Have you had a look in `dmesg` to see if says anything there?

Comment: You seem to have 1GB of swap for 96GB of RAM. Nothing wrong with that in itself but if some process needs more than what is free and there is no available swap to free up some of the inactive pages - you might end up tripping the VM heuristics. Is it possible you create a let's say 32G Swap file and activate it and see if that makes a difference? Also what is the output of cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory ?

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is `0`. The only thing relevant in `dmesg` is some lines like `system 00:0a: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] could not be reserved`. Is there a way to narrow down the nature of the ENOMEM error?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't hitting ulimit on the process?

Comment: I am not close to the ulimit for data. I don't think I'm hitting any of the other ones, either, but I'm not sure how to check them all.

Comment: @led23head, I come late, but I have the same kind of issue (also concerning physic simulations :-/ ) I also have `ENOMEM` set after loading a large amount of data. `system(NULL)` retruns `0`, meaning that it can't create a shell to execute the external command.Did you finally find a solution ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd, I never really found out what was going on. The code in question has undergone quite an overhaul and cleanup since this problem, and we haven't seen this issue surface recently, as far as I know. This might suggest that previous memory errors indeed corrupted the heap, and now they're fixed. However, it's impossible to state that for certain. Never tried `system(NULL)`.